# deep first search, python

Tags: python

Estoy programando el algoritmo Depth first search en Python, es mi primera vez usando Python por lo que no estoy muy familiarizada con su notación. Este es el ejemplo que me han dado:

```
def depthFirstSearch(problem):
    stack = util.Stack()
    stack.push((problem.getStartState(),[]))
    explored = set()
    while not stack.isEmpty():
        temp = stack.pop()
        if problem.isGoalState(temp[0]):
            return temp[1]
        explored.add(temp[0])
        for n in problem.getSuccessors(temp[0]):
            if n[0] not in explored and n[0] not in stack.list:
                stack.push((n[0], temp[1] + [n[1]]))

    return []
```

No entiendo cuando haces `pop` en el stack y lo metes en la variable temporal para poder evaluarlo, eso hace referencia a solo un valor? o varios valores?.
Cuando luego llama a `temp[0]` y `temp[1]` a qué se esta refiriendo ahi? 
Por lo que entiendo cuando esta haciendo pop tiene que ser de una cadena a la que luego accede a sus distintos valores pero no estoy segura.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python tiene un tipado blando, lo que quiere decir que las variables no son de ningun tipo hasta que les asignas algo, en tu caso, cuando haces `stack.push((problem.getStartState(),[]))` estás diciendo que la pila va a contener tuplas, es decir, guardas dos valores por cada posición de la pila (aunque esos 2 valores en realidad son listas). Por tanto, al hacer `pop` obtienes una tupla de dos valores con lo que `temp[0]` accede al primero y `temp[1]` al segundo